# Best Practices for version control with multiple projects

Tags: language-agnostic, version-control

I have several projects with a very large over-lapping code-base. We've just recently started using SVN so I'm trying to figure out how I should be using it.

The problem is that as I'm finishing a task on one project, I'm starting a task on another, with some overlap. Often there's a lot of interrupt driven development as well. So, my code is never really in a completely stable state that I feel comfortable checking in.

The result is that we're not really using the VC system, which is a VERY bad thing, we all know... so, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a personal branch of the code and merge in changes.  At least you will have some version control for your own changes, in case you need to roll back.  Once you are comfortable with the state that your branch is in, merge that branch back into the trunk.

You can also check out a branch for each task, instead of one for each individual.  You can also merge changes to your branch from the trunk if someone changes the trunk, and you want your branch to reflect the changes.

This is a common way to use SVN, although there are other workflows.  I have worked on projects where I was afraid to commit(I would break the build possibly) because we did not effectively use branching.

Branching is really powerful in helping your workflow, use it until you're comfortable with the idea of merging.

Edit: 'Checking out a branch' refers to creating branch in your branches folder, and then checking out that branch.  The standard svn repository structure consists of the folders trunk, tags, and branches at the root.

Answer (score 1):

> So, my code is never really in a completely stable state that I feel comfortable checking in.

Why is that ?
If your branch is appropriate for your work (with a good naming convention for instance), everyone will know its HEAD is not always stable.
In this kind of "working" branch, just put some tag along the way to indicate some "stable code points" (which can then be queried by any tester to be deployed).
Any other version on that working branch is just made to record changes, even though the current state is not stable.

Then later you merge all on a branch supposed to represent a stable state.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS, you are able to create 'Shelf Sets' (I'm not sure what they'd be called in other source control providers). When you shelve some code, you are saving it to your repository, but not checking it in.

The reason this is important is that if you are working on Bug XXXX, and you fix half of the code, but it's not stable and not 'check-in-able', but you get assigned to NewFeature YYYY, you SHOULD NOT continue working with the same code base. You should 'Shelf' your Bug XXXX code, then return your local codebase to the latest checked-in code, and implement NewFeature YYYY.

This way you are keeping your check-ins atomic. You don't have to worry about losing your work, because it is still held by the repository (so if your computer bursts into flames, you don't have to burst into tears), and you aren't mixing your fixes for XXXX with your new code for YYYY. 
Then, once you are asked to go back to XXXX (assuming you've checked in YYYY) you can just unshelve your 'shelf set' and jump right back into it where you left off.

Answer (score 0):

Either accept that the code in SVN is not in a completely stable state and check it in anyway (and reserve time for stabilization and refactoring every X days/weeks so the code doesn't degrade too much).

Or force your team to work in a more structured way with minimal interruption based development so you can check in good code.

The first option is not ideal (but better then no source control), the second is probably impossible - there is no third option.

If you don't have time to get the code to a stable state you defiantly don't have the time to branch and merge all the time.

Comment: The problem is that we're a 7 person (2 engineers) company, so we can't really afford to be that structured. Also, the "team" is just me.

Answer (score 0):

In distributed sourcecontrol systems like GIT, you commit to your local repository. Only when you push your code, it's 'committed' to the remote repository.

In this way, its much easier to 'safe' your work in between.